# CSS Bug: Sliding one image among multiple images in a carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am trying to implement bootstrap carousel to rotate or slide one image at a time among the multiple images in carousel.

The answer here works perfectly fine for a single carousel placed in a page. [Bootstrap: Slide only one image among the multiple images in an item of the carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926919/bootstrap-slide-only-one-image-among-the-multiple-images-in-an-item-of-the-caro)

But I'm using multiple carousel inside single page. So, I modified the existing to target only the certain carousel. Right after changing css, the carousel behaved weird and now slides with a annoying animation like thing. Demo here: http://www.bootply.com/hL5UY8Jnaw

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was somehow able to correct that CSS bug using some classes and bit more css. You can check the working version here http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/vvl6r