# How to constant background image in bootstrap slider?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, background-image

I am using bootstrap slider(https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/) and i have to constant background image.I want to use only one image in background so that only content will slide.You guys can check link in that there are 3 images in background(slide one,slide two, slide three).I have to use only slide one image.would you help me in this?

Comment: Please check the html code carefully.
Here is a look.

<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One');">
if you change "Slide One" as you want, the text of image will be only changed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Josef,No issue for that i will add other image.i given only example.

Comment: That's great. No problem.

Comment: U Can Learn More About That in The Below Link [Only One Image In Bootstrap Carousel to Slide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926919/bootstrap-slide-only-one-image-among-the-multiple-images-in-an-item-of-the-caro)

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Tamilmani, That's different issue.I have to display only one image.only content will slide after clicked.

Comment: You guys can check this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634480/how-to-display-background-image-for-quote-slider).This is the same issue i am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below code

```
Css
    .carousel-inner {
        height: 100%;
            background-image:url('http://placehold.it/300?text=placehold');
    }

HTML
<!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="font-size: 32px;text-align: center;padding-top: 100px;">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="font-size: 32px;text-align: center;padding-top: 100px;">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- Set the third background image using inline CSS below. -->
                <div class="fill" style="font-size: 32px;text-align: center;padding-top: 100px;">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Caption 3</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Mohamed.it's working but there is some issue in the heigh of background image...

Comment: My image height is 500px, After change background image it showing almost 100px

Comment: Please share your original link i will check the height issue.

Comment: Cool!!!! i add padding and worked perfectly...Thanks Mr.Mohamed.Thank you very much for this.